# Flatten Truffle Solidity Contracts for Etherscan's `Verify Contract Code` Feature

Tags: solidity, truffle, etherscan, abi

Etherscan.io has a `Verify Contract Code` feature that takes the inputs `Solidity Contract Code` and `Constructor Arguments ABI-encoded`.

**Question:** Is there a tool to flatten your solidity contracts (written in conjunction with the use of Truffle), and maybe even generate the ABI-encoded constructor arguments, so as to speed up your use of Etherscan's contract verification feature?

Tried Blockcat's python script `solidity-flattener` but could never get it to work. Hoping to discover a new alternative method.

Comment: My code compiles, but I still cannot create a flatfile. Any suggestions? <pre>
user@eth:/code/myproject$ truffle compile
user@eth:/code/myproject$ touch contracts/CtdToken.sol
user@eth:/code/myproject$ truffle compile
Compiling ./contracts/CtdToken.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/InterfaceUpgradeAgent.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/UpgradableToken.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/Withdrawable.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/lifecycle/Pausable.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol...
Compiling zeppelin-s

Answer (score 7):

I've used this one in the past, with very good results and minimal setup:
https://github.com/oraclesorg/oracles-combine-solidity

```
git clone https://github.com/oraclesorg/oracles-combine-solidity
cd oracles-combine-solidity
npm install
npm start "path_to_not_flat_contract_definition_file.sol"
```

Comment: Much quicker option

Answer (score 4):

I use this which is built to work with Truffle specifically and it works great, although it's early in its development: https://github.com/alcuadrado/truffle-flattener

Answer (score 3):

Try to use

`--solc-paths=zeppelin-solidity=$(pwd)/node_modules/zeppelin-solidity/`

Here is example from my case

```
solidity_flattener contracts/MyTicketSale.sol --solc-paths=zeppelin-solidity=$(pwd)/node_modules/zeppelin-solidity/ --output result.sol
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I used this option and it works.

Comment: How do you determine entry point? e.g. https://etherscan.io/address/0x44c3fab0ae93ac02ae7a218c51e8a0e5e64c34df#code

Answer (score 3):

I've just released a simple-to-install Solidity Flattener - https://github.com/bokkypoobah/SolidityFlattener

Comment: If you, like I did, tried Blockcat's solidity-flattener and failed to get it working, try this tool. It really works!

Answer (score 3):

### Truffle Flattener

Yes, there is `truffle-flattener` (https://github.com/nomiclabs/truffle-flattener/) that combines all your smart contracts files into one. And it works well with Truffle.
Here is how to use it:

1) Install globally:

```
npm install -g truffle-flattener
```

2) Use it, for example, to flatten your smart contract 'SimpleToken.sol' like this:

```
truffle-flattener contracts/SimpleToken.sol > FlattenedSimpleToken.sol
```

(Simple step by step tutorial to use truffle flattener and verify your code manually on etherscan.io: https://www.sitepoint.com/flattening-contracts-debugging-remix/)

---

### Verify with OpenZeppelin SDK

However, if you like to do a fully automated etherscan.io verification, there is `openzeppelin verify` And here is how to use it: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/verify-with-openzeppelin-sdk/1206

Answer (score 2):

I created `truffle-plugin-verify` to automate Truffle contract verification on Etherscan.

---

1. Install the plugin with npm

```sh
npm install truffle-plugin-verify
```

2. Add the plugin to your `truffle.js` or `truffle-config.js` file

```js
module.exports = {
  /* ... rest of truffle-config */

  plugins: [
    'truffle-plugin-verify'
  ]
}
```

3. Generate an API Key on your Etherscan account (see the [Etherscan website](https://etherscan.io/apis))
4. Add your Etherscan API key to your truffle config

```js
module.exports = {
  /* ... rest of truffle-config */

  api_keys: {
    etherscan: 'MY_API_KEY'
  }
}
```

---

After migrating your contract contract to a public network, you are able to verify it on Etherscan by running:

```
truffle run verify ContractName [--network networkName]
```

---

More information can be found on [the repository](https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-plugin-verify) or in my article [Automatically verify Truffle smart contracts on Etherscan](https://kalis.me/check-events-solidity-smart-contract-test-truffle/).